# OneDrive file upload unexpected 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-401, onedrive

Im trying to upload a file using the OneDrive API. Authentication works as expected. Authentication uses `files.readwrite.all` and `offline_access` scopes. Other calls like getting the files of the users also work as expected. When tring to upload a file I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error.

First I create an upload session and get the upload URL using the code below:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken.ToString());

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    response = await client.PostAsync("/v1.0/drive/root:" + path + "/" + file.FileName + ":/createUploadSession", null);


    string uploadUrl = (string)JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())["uploadUrl"];
}
```

This works as expected. The response status code is 200 and I get the upload URL. Next I want to upload the file using the upload URL. The content contains the bytes of the first chunk I want to upload. Content-Length and Content-Range are also set correctly. I'm sending the content using the same client to the upload URL using a put request.

```
ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(chunk);
content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", (contentRangeEnd - contentRangeBegin).ToString());
content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "bytes " + contentRangeBegin + "-" + (contentRangeEnd - 1) + "/" + allBytes.Length);

response = await client.PutAsync(uploadUrl, content);
```

The put request results in a 401 error. The access token seems to be valid because other calls like getting the files work as expected.

How do I resolve the 401 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the authorization header (Bearer + access token) from the chunk upload Put request. It is not required by Graph API and maybe it is causing the issue.

Comment: This is correct. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session): Including the Authorization header when issuing the PUT call may result in a HTTP 401 Unauthoized response. The Authoization header and bearer token should only be sent when issueing the POST during the first step. It should be not be included when issueing the PUT.